# php create directory

Tags: php

I am creating a directory and I am getting the error

Warning: chmod() [function.chmod]: No such file or directory in /home/www/public_html/console/pubs-add.php on line 104

The php file that is running the code is in www/console and the directory that I am trying to create is in www/images/gallery.

I have tried many variations of setting the path such as ../images/gallery or home/www but nothing seesm to work

```
define("PATH", "/www/images/gallery");

$dir = 'a1234';

$targetfilename = PATH . '/' . $dir;

if (!is_file($dir) && !is_dir($dir)) {
    mkdir($dir); //create the directory
    chmod($targetfilename, 0777); //make it writable
}
```

Comment: Does PHP have write access to `/www/images/gallery`?

Comment: `mkdir( $dir )` is likely returning `false`. Might want to check the return value of it before attempting to `chmod` a file within.

Comment: 777 gives ALL permissions to ANY user. Figure out what exact permissions you need to grant, don't just put 777 on stuff: you're exposing full permissions for hackers to do things with your system.

Comment: yes I just set them for testing and then lock down everything for release

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `mkdir` command just uses `$dir`, which is just 'a1234' (in the current working directory). This will fail (and make the `chmod` fail too).

The solution: you probably want to prefix $dir with PATH...

Comment: yes I think this is the problem, what would you think the correct path would be?

Answer (score 2):

It makes the `$dir` in your current working directory, however, it doesn't mean that this equals your `$targetfilename`. I would say that you have to do `mkdir($targetfilename)` rather than `mkdir($dir)`.

Answer (score 2):

Dear chmod() create some time problem. So i will suggest u that use this
mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0700);
if u want the created directory should be ready and wirtable then use this
mkdir("/path/to/my/dir", 0777);

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you cannot chmod a file that you haven't made. For that reason, I've changed the line

```
$task = chmod($targetfilename, 0777); //make it writable
```

to

```
$task = chmod($dir, 0755); //make folder writable
```

Tip: If you want a folder to be writable, chmod it to 755 and not 777. 777 is for files.